# Can we set any specific folder in file browser of blender?

Tags: file-browser

I have made the specific folder save folder for blender. Now every time I want to save a new project I have to manually visit that folder to save the project. Can I just set the folder in blender file browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set folder in favourite just select the folder which you want to add on file browser favourite. Press mouse right click: then select add bookmark. The folder will be added to the favourites in file browser of blender.